# Convert MP3 Audio File to Numpy array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, mp3

I've tried many things to open and convert an audio file into a numpy array but nothing works.

```
import numpy as np
import pyglet

song = pyglet.media.load('sample-000000.mp3')
np.array(song)
```

I want an array of numbers, not an array containing a pyglet file.

```
Out[1]: 
array(<pyglet.media.codecs.wmf.WMFSource object at 0x00000222A8118808>,
      dtype=object)
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

use pydub

```
import pydub
import numpy as np
a = pydub.AudioSegment.from_mp3("file.mp3")
arry = np.array(a.get_array_of_samples())
print(arry)
```